A mixed first-person 3D/top-down 2D game for DOS, probably from the 1990s, about a boy protagonist escaping from being abducted by aliens
The way I remember it, I first played this game on a CD (sadly, I do not recall the name) that contained dozens of DOS games. I think that this was in 1995, but I am not sure. The following is an incomplete list of the games on it.

"Adventure" (1987), "Aldo's Adventure" (1987), "Ancients 1: Death Watch" (1991), "Aqua Man" (1993), "Arctic Adventure" (1991), "AstroFire" (April 29, 1994)
"Baron Baldric: A Grave Overture" (November 1992), "Battle for Atlantis" (1990), "Billy the Kid Returns!" (August 1, 1993), "Bio Menace" (1993), "Blockout" (1989), "Bolo Adventures III" (1994), "Brix" (1993)
"CD-MAN" (June 1989), "Chopper Commando" (1990), "Commander Keen 1: Marooned on Mars" (December 14, 1990), "Commander Keen 4: Secret of the Oracle" (December 15, 1991), "Cosmo's Cosmic Adventure" (1992), "Crusher Castle II" (1993), "Crystal Caves" (1991), "Cyberbox" (August 1991)
"Dark Ages: Volume 1 – Prince of Destiny" (February 1, 1991), "Diamond Dash" (March 2, 1993), "Dschump!" (1993), "Dungeons of Drakklor" (1992)
"Electro Body" (February 21, 1992), "Elevators from Hell" (1992), "Elfland" (1992), "Executioners" (1992)
"FBI Fred" (1992)
"Galacta: The Battle for Saturn" (November 1992), "Galactic Battle" (January 1990), "Gateworld" (1993), "Green" (1992)
"Halloween Harry" ["Alien Carnage"] (October 10, 1993), "Heavy Water Jogger" (1992), "Helious" (1993), "Hugo's House of Horrors" (January 1, 1990), "Hugo II: Whodunit?" (1991), "Hugo III: Jungle of Doom" (February 20, 1992), "Humbug" (1990)
"Jetpack" (1993), "Jetpack: Christmas Special" (1993), "Jill of the Jungle" (1992), "Joust VGA" (April 18, 1990), "Jumpjet" (1990)
"Last Half of Darkness" (1989), "Llamatron 2112" (1992)
"Major Stryker" (1993), "Megatron VGA" (1991), "Mice Men" (1992), "MinerVGA" (1989), "Missile Attack" (1990), "Monster Bash" (1993), "Monuments of Mars" (1991)
"Night VGA" ["The Endless Night"] (1993), "Nukem" (1992), "Nyet III: The Revenge of the Mutant Stones" (1993)
"One Must Fall" (1993)
"Paganitzu" (1991), "Perestroika" (1990)
"Sandstorm" (1993), "Sea Quest" (1992), "Secret Agent" (February 1, 1992), "Silicon City" (1993), "Skunny: Lost in Space" (1993), "Skunny: Save Our Pizzas!" (1993), "Skunny's Desert Raid" (1993), "Slan" (1993), "Slick Joe 1: Lost in Reno" (January 29, 1993), "Snarf" (January 1988), "Solar Winds: The Escape" (1993), "Starfire" (1992), "Superfly" (1990)
"The Adventures of Captain Comic" (May 1, 1988), "The Catacomb Abyss 3D" (1992), "Treasure Hunt Math" (1993), "Tron" (1992)
"Xerix" (December 1992)

Based on the list, the game that I am looking for is a DOS game that was released in the period between 1987 and 1994. It was a colourful game, so it had to be VGA, which would narrow it down to the period between 1991 and 1994.
The first screen is a cutscene showing an alien spaceship in Earth's orbit. The aliens basically resemble green octopi, but they have mouths containing fangs below their eyes. The alien leader wants the human race wiped out, and so he says, "Fire phasers!" The gunner obeys, and…one yellow drop comes out of the gun and falls down, like a drop of water out of a faucet. The leader says, "I SAID FIRE PHASERS!" The gunner has to tell him that their guns have unfortunately run out of energy (because the journey to Earth drained up their batteries). The leader is not happy to hear this. The gunner follows up by explaining that if they capture one human and process them, it will give them the energy that they need to attack. The leader gives the order to beam a human up immediately.
The second screen is the other part of the cutscene showing a boy lying in his bed. The boy's name might be Billy or Joey, but I am not sure. The narration states that he is lying in his bed, completely unaware of what is about to happen next. What happens is that he changes into a few different colours, ending with white. I guess that is him being beamed up into the spaceship, just like the "Star Trek" franchise.
The third screen is where the gameplay takes place. The game takes place in a corridor on the spaceship. It has a first-person perspective. You can only go in one direction, and that is forward. The boy is carrying a laser gun, and I think that it has a limited number of shots. You have to press a key (or a button) to move forward one step at a time. Each time you step forward, there is a random chance of being attacked by an alien. An opening will appear in the left wall, the ceiling, or the right wall. An alien with a fanged mouth will come out of the opening and try to bite the boy to death. Naturally, you must use the laser gun (either by clicking on the alien or pressing a key that will shoot in that direction) to drive the alien attacker back. I think that there are three keys, one for shooting in each direction. I think that the boy's health starts at 100%, and that you are trying to prevent it from dropping to 0%. I think that a portrait of the boy is next to the health. The boy starts out looking healthy, but he will look like an undead zombie if he dies. I also think that there are three lives, and that you will lose one each time the boy dies. As I remember it, that part of the game plays like a very simplified version of "Wolfenstein 3D".
Once the boy reaches the end of the corridor, he will get into an escape pod. This leads to the fourth screen. It has a top-down perspective. I think that you can only move left or right. You are trying to dodge asteroids/debris as you guide the boy back to Earth. The escape pod is very fragile, so one collision with an asteroid will destroy it and cost you a life.
That was very detailed, wasn't it? I will try to sum it up.

Platform: DOS
Date released: 1991–1994
Genre: Action
Perspective: First-person, Top-down
Gameplay: Shooter, Arcade

I hope that someone can help me find this game.

Good news, everyone! I have finally found the game that I was looking for!
The game is titled "Nocturnal Nightmares". It is a 1992 DOS game developed by Robin Ward and Martin Salomon. The protagonist is a boy named Jimmy. The game consists of shooting aliens in a corridor and then navigating an escape pod back to Earth.
The title screen looks like this.

Source: From the screenshots section of the Mobygames entry for this game.
Funny enough, Robin Ward has a YouTube video where he talks about the game and what a remastered version would look like. By the way, the game never got past the shareware stage, because the two developers knew that the game was not that good to begin with.
Well, good or not, it deserves to be remembered, in my humble opinion!

Not bad for a game by a 13 year old!

Have never seen that before - glad you found it! Do accept your answer when you can!
